# AVPlayer only plays video after db is reseeded

Tags: swift, video, core-data, avplayer

I am using a series of 4 functions to manage playing a playlist of videos sequentially in AVPlayer.

```
    func setupPlayer(path : String?) {
        var url = currentVid!.url! //path ?? currentVid!.url!
        print("setting up player")
        self.player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: url))
        self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
        self.videoPlayer!.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)
        self.playerLayer!.frame = view.frame
        videoPlayer!.isHidden = false
        self.player!.play()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(videoUpdate), name: Notification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player!.currentItem)
    }
    
    @objc func videoUpdate(start : Bool = false) {
        videoPlayer?.isHidden = false
        setCurrentVid()
        setupPlayer(path: currentVid?.url)
        self.player?.play()
        print ("update ended")
    }
    
    func updateCurrentPath() {
        currentPath = currentPath == nil ? 0 : currentPath! + 1
        currentPath = currentPath! % currentVideos!.count
        print("currentPath updated to \(currentPath)")
    }
    
    func setCurrentVid(updating: Bool = true) -> DBVideo {
        if updating {
            updateCurrentPath()
        }
        currentVid = currentVideos![currentPath!]
        panel?.highlightIndicator(currentPath!)
        return currentVideos![currentPath!]
    }
```

The AVPlayer gets the correct string, retrieved from a CoreData Entity field, which is a String. if I've deleted an reseeded the CoreData DB from a .yaml file, it performs as expected. If I don't and I'm retrieving the data from the DB, it doesn't play the videos.

I looks as if, through debugging and print statements, that at the point where the AVPlayer is being created, that the same string is being supplied in both situations.

Some code that removes the playerLayer and the player and recreates them has been added to try different scenarios, and I don't really think that's the issue, but I am stumped.

The issue seems it might be connected to the fact that there is a data fault upstream: there is a DB Entity called Curriculum that contains Assignment, that in turn contain Challenges, that themselves are the source of NSSets of Videos, which is the source of the url strings. But why should that matter, if the String is delivered to the AVPlayer? I am clearly missing something.

UPDATE: Adding a line to check the AVPlayer currentItem

```
    @objc func videoUpdate(start : Bool = false) {
        videoPlayer!.isHidden = false
        setCurrentVid()
        setupPlayer(path: currentVid?.url)
        print("player current item \(player?.currentItem)")
        self.player!.play()
        print ("update ended")
    }
```

produces

```
setting up player
player current item Optional(<AVPlayerItem: 0x600000024d70, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x60000029ea20, URL = file:///Users/dandonaldson/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/05DB48E2-AA3B-445E-A982-B8B708006B27/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1176693C-90F4-4AFB-9DD8-74F6819B9BA5/VideoMentor.app/move%20with%20numbers.mov>>)
update ended
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer turned out to be simple, and I could have spent less time figuring it out. The problem was that at the time I rebuilt the database, seeding it from a .yaml file, I was generating the full path, based on the current value of Bundle.main.

This didn't persist, of course, so when I called up a video, it used the pre-generated url path, which did not find a file if not in the same session that populated the db. I think that in a deployment, it would be the same Bundle.main value, so this would have been fine. Also, if I'd had an iPad to try it on, it I think would have worked as it was.

So this is kind of the worst fix, something included to get around the conditions that exist in the development environment.

I eliminated the url field in the CoreData schema, and whenever a file is requested to play, I regenerate it in a static method. Now works fine.